# Ошибка при вызове деструктора

Tags: c++, visual-c++

помогите разобраться с проблемой, она довольно распространенная и на форуме куча сообщений про это но в моей программе я никак не могу найти где я ошибся, нужен ваш взгляд со стороны.
Вот код:

```
#pragma once
#include <cstring>

class vec
{
public:
    vec()
    {
        m_size = offset;
        m_len = 0;
        m_vector = new int[m_size];
        memset(m_vector, 0, sizeof(m_vector));
    }
    vec(size_t size)
    {
        m_size = size;
        m_len = 0;
        m_vector = new int[m_size];
        memset(m_vector, 0, sizeof(m_vector));
    }
    vec(const vec& orig)
        :
        m_size(orig.m_size),
        m_len(orig.m_len),
        m_vector(nullptr)
    {
        m_vector = new int[m_size];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < m_len; ++i)
        {
            m_vector[i] = orig.m_vector[i];
        }
    }
    ~vec()
    {
        if (m_vector != nullptr)
        {
            delete[] m_vector;
            m_vector = nullptr;
        }
    }
    size_t GetSize()
    {
        return m_size;
    }
    size_t GetLength()
    {
        return m_len;
    }
    int* GetValue()
    {
        return m_vector;
    }
    vec& operator= (const vec& rhs)
    {
        if (m_vector)
        {
            delete[] m_vector;
            m_vector = nullptr;
            m_len = rhs.m_len;
            m_vector = new int[m_size];
            for (size_t i = 0; i < m_len; ++i)
            {
                m_vector[i] = rhs.m_vector[i];
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }
    int& operator[] (size_t index)
    {
        return m_vector[index];
    }
    bool operator== (const vec& rhs)
    {
        if (m_len != rhs.m_len)
            return false;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_len; ++i)
        {
            if (m_vector[i] != rhs.m_vector[i])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    bool operator!= (const vec& rhs)
    {
        if (!(this == &rhs))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    void push_back(int value)
    {
        if (m_len == m_size)
        {
            vec v = vec(m_size * (m_size / 2));
            v = *this;
            this->m_size = v.m_size;
            *this = v;
        }
        m_vector[m_len] = value;
        m_len++;
    }
    void erase(unsigned int pos)
    {
        m_vector[pos] = m_vector[m_len - 1];
        --m_len;
    }
    void erase(unsigned int begin, unsigned int end)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = begin; i <= end; ++i)
        {
            m_vector[i] = m_vector[m_len - i - 1];

        }
        m_len -= end - begin;
    }
    void pop_back()
    {
        m_vector[m_len - 1] = 0;
        --m_len;
    }
private:
    static constexpr size_t offset = 8;
    size_t m_size;
    size_t m_len;
    int* m_vector;
};

#include "Vec.h"

int main()
{
    vec v0;
    v0.push_back(2);
    v0.push_back(22);
    v0.push_back(234);
    v0.push_back(2325);
    printf("\n");
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v0.GetLength(); ++i)
    {
        printf("%d ", v0[i]);
    }
    vec v1(v0);
    v1.push_back(532);
    v1.push_back(2324);
    v1.push_back(1321);
    v1.push_back(6532);
    v1.push_back(42);
    printf("\n");
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v1.GetLength(); ++i)
    {
        printf("%d ", v1[i]);
    }
    vec v2;
    v2 = v1;
    v2.push_back(456);
    v2.push_back(452);
    v2.push_back(224);
    v2.push_back(12);
    v2.push_back(698);
    v2.erase(4, 7);
    v2.pop_back();
    printf("\n");
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v2.GetLength(); ++i)
    {
        printf("%d ", v2[i]);
    }
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: так а в чем проблема?

Comment: Где и какая ошибка возникает?

Comment: А зачем вы пытаетесь присвоить значение удаленному объекту?

Comment: ошибка еще на вызове dlete[] в деструкторе

Comment: где конкретно я пытаюсь присвоить значение удаленному объекту?

Comment: а что вот это вообще:  `memset(m_vector, 0, sizeof(m_vector));`? Что это за полет фантазии?

Comment: просто заполнение нулями, если убрать ничего не измениться, можно по теме вопроса пожалуйста

Comment: @UserName а это разве не по теме? Вот посмотрите что делает функция, которую вы применяете: http://all-ht.ru/inf/prog/c/func/memset.html. Тут как минимум потенциальный выход за пределы выделенной памяти

Comment: `*this = v;` - хитро

Comment: Igor спасибо!) действительно полная белиберда, я исправил на this->m_vector = v.m_vector;

Comment: Нет, подождите, теперь-то уж точно будет ошибка в деструкторе при повторном освобождении памяти.

Comment: да, не заметил что в release запустил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Оператор присваивания**

```
vec& operator= (const vec& rhs)
{
    // 1. нет проверки на присваивание самому себе
    if (m_vector)
    // 2. что это за проверка??
    // т.е. если текущий вектор пустой - то присваивать не будем?
    {
        // если беспокоетесь за удаление нулевого указателя -
        // не бойтесь delete не сломается (ему можно передавать нулевые указатели)
        delete[] m_vector;
        m_vector = nullptr; // это лишнее
        m_len = rhs.m_len;
        m_vector = new int[m_size]; // интересный момент
        // выделение новой памяти под такой же размер что и был ранее?
        for (size_t i = 0; i < m_len; ++i)
        // т.е. если размер текущего массива был меньше чем количество элементов
        // массива-аргумента тут будет выход за границы
        {
            m_vector[i] = rhs.m_vector[i];
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Учитывая все замечания можно написать следующий оператор присваивания:

```
vec& operator= (const vec& rhs)
{
    if (&rhs == this) return *this; // проверка на присваивание себе

    int new_size = rhs.m_size; // новый размер этого (this) массива
    int new_len = rhs.m_len;   // новая длина массива
    int* new_vector = new int[new_size]; // новый массив
    for (size_t i = 0; i < new_len; ++i) // копируем все данный в новый массив
        new_vector[i] = rhs.m_vector[i];
    // теперь уверенно удаляем старый массив
    delete[] m_vector;
    m_vector = new_vector; // запоминаем новый вектор
    // и запонимаем новые размеры
    m_size = new_size;
    m_len = new_len;

    return *this;
}
```

**Функция вставки элемента в конец массива**

```
void push_back(int value)
{
    if (m_len == m_size)
    {
        // новый размер вычисляется странным образом
        // т.е. если массив имеет размер 10000
        // ему вычислится следующий размер 5000 * 10000 = 50000000
        // многовато
        // популярные реализации векторов используют старый размер * 1,5 или на 2
        vec v = vec(m_size * (m_size / 2));
        // тут вобще магический подход
        v = *this;
        this->m_size = v.m_size;
        *this = v;
    }
    m_vector[m_len] = value;
    m_len++;
}
```

Работающий `push_back` будет выглядеть примерно следующим образом:

```
void push_back(int value)
{
    if (m_len == m_size)
    {
        int new_size = m_size * 1.5;    // вычисляем новый размер
        int* new_vector = new int[new_size]; // выделяем память под новый массив
        for (int i = 0; i < m_len; ++i) // копируем данные из текущего массива в новый
        {
            new_vector[i] = m_vector[i];
        }
        delete[] m_vector; // теперь удаляем старый массив
        m_vector = new_vector; // запоминаем наш новый массив
        m_size = new_size; // запоминаем новый размер
    }
    m_vector[m_len] = value;
    m_len++;
}
```